# flutter run gives error after installing the app in device

Tags: flutter

**flutter run**

Error after installing the apk in the avd.

Error connecting to the service protocol: failed to connect to http://127.0.0.1:50697/_-T9aBxhOtM=/

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69730208/9942927. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

User 0.0.0.0 insted of 127.0.0.1 and make sure your service is running on defined port or you can check on which port your service is running and try to connect with that port. It will work

Comment: Error connecting to the service protocol: failed to connect to http://127.0.0.1:52920/ZEm3TsbX6rY=/   this is the error i get in the console when i try to run 'flutter run'... I didn't get your answer.../.